# Convert HTML to XML using XSLT to process with SSIS

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Any idea how to get a xslt from this html page. Note I just wanna get these values.Thanks in advance.

```
<
     <table style="font-size: 12px; border-color: #BFBFBF; border-style: solid; border-width: .05em; border-collapse: collapse; width: 1100px;">
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><B>Total Steps in Transaction</B></td>
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1">4</td>
        </tr>
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><B>Total Transaction Response Time</B></td>
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1">2.2367 (seconds)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><B>Ave. Response Time Per Step</B></td>
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1">0.5592 (seconds)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><B>Total Transaction Outage</B></td>
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1">140 (minutes)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><B>Transaction Uptime Percentage</B></td>
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1">99.69%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><B>Total Transaction Success Rate</B></td>
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1">99.63%  (35474 Attempted, 35343 Successful)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1"><B># of Notifications</B></td>
          <td style="padding-left: 3px; padding-right: 3px; border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;" nowrap="nowrap" rowspan="1" colspan="1">13</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to indicate what XML you want to generate (unless you only want answers from people who understand SSIS?)

If you just want a sequence of elements like

```
<item label="Total Steps in Transaction" value="4"/>
```

then you just need a template rule like

```
<xsl:template match="tr">
  <item label="{td[1]}" value="{td[2]}"/>
</xsl:template>
```